# How to properly set and query siteMetadata in Gatsbyjs?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

The issue I am running into is that when I set a key-value pair in the gatsby-config.js file I am not able to see the data inside GraphiQL. I am following the documentation and using keys that are used in the example code. See here for the documentation: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-config/#sitemetadata

Here is my `gatsby-config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `My Photography Site`,
    description: `Just the best`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `src`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
      options: {
        pathToConfigModule: `src/utils/typography`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Here is my GraphiQL query (after restarting the development server to reload the gatsby-config.js file):

```js
query SiteQuery {
  site {
    siteMetadata {
      title
      description
    }
  }
}
```

Expected results from the GraphiQL:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "site": {
      "siteMetadata": {
        "title": "My Photography Site",
        "description": "Just the best"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the actual result of the GraphiQL:

```js
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"description\" on type \"SiteSiteMetadata\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 7
        }
      ],
      "stack": [
        "GraphQLError: Cannot query field \"description\" on type \"SiteSiteMetadata\".",
        "    at Object.Field (/mnt/c/Users/Spencer/dev/gatsbyjs/hello-world/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/FieldsOnCorrectType.js:64:31)",
        "    at Object.enter (/mnt/c/Users/Spencer/dev/gatsbyjs/hello-world/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:334:29)",
        "    at Object.enter (/mnt/c/Users/Spencer/dev/gatsbyjs/hello-world/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:385:25)",
        "    at visit (/mnt/c/Users/Spencer/dev/gatsbyjs/hello-world/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:252:26)",
        "    at validate (/mnt/c/Users/Spencer/dev/gatsbyjs/hello-world/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:63:22)",
        "    at /mnt/c/Users/Spencer/dev/gatsbyjs/hello-world/node_modules/express-graphql/dist/index.js:154:52",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What is odd is that I was able to successfully create a custom key-value pair before and it worked fine. I had a key of `tagLine` and a value of `Panda Site`. The normal `title` key worked as well.

Here are the software versions I am using:

- gatsby: 2.5.12
- node: v12.1.0
- npm: 6.9.0

I am running using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Let me know if you would like any other config files, including package.json.

Comment: Did you try restarting `gatsby develop` and refreshing GraphiQL after editing `gatsby-config.js`?

Comment: @ksav Yes I have, to no avail.

Comment: What about stopping gatsby develop, removing cache & public folders `rm -rf ./.cache/ && rm -rf ./public/`, restarting `gatsby develop`, and then hard reloading the GraphiQL browser tab?

Comment: Can you try rollback to a previous version like `"gatsby-plugin-feed": "2.0.9"`. That helped me. I'm having issues with the latest version of the feed and offline plugins and it seems that has been the accepted resolution for now while they look into it.

Comment: Tried `gatsby clean && gatsby develop`?